# React Router navigation issue in Firefox after reloading URL from address bar

Tags: react-router, react-router-v4

I have a navigation issue in a SPA with React 16.12 and React Router 4.3.1 which only happens in the Firefox browser.

For example, starting from the URL /recommendedProducts I navigate to the URL /forms. If I reload the /forms page by pressing enter in the address bar, and immediately I press the browser back button, the URL changes to /recommendedProducts but it doesn't refresh. Investigating and comparing the behavior between Firefox and Chrome I noticed that the popstate event is not triggered in Firefox.

Here are the routes:

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/recommendedProducts" component={RecommendedProducts} />
...
    <Route path="/forms" component={Forms} />
</Switch>
```

If, instead of reloading the /forms page this way, I press F5 all is OK, the browser back button works as expected.

Why Firefox doesn't trigger the popstate event and how can inform React Router to refresh the page?

**EDIT:**
I just find out this React Router issue, this is exactly the problem:
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/837

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem has to do with the Firefox cache. As indicated in https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/837 defining the unload event handler disables it.

Here the official docs:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Releases/1.5/Using_Firefox_1.5_caching

Previously I tried also to use the pageshow and pagehide events by refreshing the page from there but they are not always triggered.